# JavaScript libraries / toolkits that support binding JSON data to HTML controls?

Tags: javascript, html, json, data-binding

Are there any JavaScript libraries or Toolkits that allow me to bind the JSON data to html controls on the client?

So essentially I should be able specify the object property to which a html control should be bound. Hence when the form receives the JSON data, the controls are updated, and when the controls are updated, the data should be updated to JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ext](http://extjs.com/) has an excellent implementation of what you describe, and it's similarity to the old Delphi and .NET methods of binding data to controls is a little spooky (though without the GUI to see the binding it's not quite as pretty)

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/

Look up JSONStore. Beware, there is a learning curve here of a couple weeks to really start on the path.

Another option is [Perservere](http://www.persvr.org/), which is part of the DOJO toolkit. I'm not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for as I've never used it, but it appears to be robust and does a lot of things you would expect a persistent client side dataset to do.

Answer (score 0):

Itemscript describes a JSON schema language for data and applications.  http://itemscript.org

The project provides a reference implementation of Itemscript JAM (JSON application markup), a declarative markup language that's described in an Itemscript schema.

The Item Lens is an Itemscript JAM animator.   The Itemscript project goal is to provide a standard lightweight language for binding data and widgets.   The reference implementation is based on GWT.

The project will be providing a way to share Itemscripts, but is at this point taking comments on the Itemscript Schema language and developing Itemscript JAMs for common application patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at http://github.com/raid-ox/chain.js/

Answer (score 0):

I second extjs, but beware their dual license.